# i need to make it repeat asking the user for a number and printing the output and it stops when the user tells it so

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int num;

  printf ("Enter integer number  ");

  scanf ("%d", &num);

  while (num <= 1)
    {
      printf ("Enter any integer number(positive) : ");
      scanf ("%d", &num);
    }

  int total;

  total = 1;

  while (num > 1)
  {
    total = total * (num);
    num = num - 1;
  }

  printf ("total is %d", total);

  return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be

(enter number)

for examble the user enters (5)

(total is 120)

(enter number)

the user enters number (4)

(total is 24)

user enters (stop)

program stops

Comment: _I expect the code to ..._ Why would you **expect** the code to do something it clearly does not do?  Do you mean you **want** the code to do that?

Comment: It looks like you already know how to use a `while` loop - perhaps that might help ?

Comment: It may be more clear to us what you expect to see if you edit the question adding examples of what you expect the output to be... More than one example, please...

Comment: To start, try adding `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` calls.

Comment: @JohnGordon English isn't my first language so you can imagine  how hard it is to explain something in another language and yes i meant want the code to do that

Comment: @John3136 Yes I know how to use the while loop but I'm still a beginner and im stuck on how to make it repeat without messing things up

Comment: @Fe2O3 ohhh ok i get now

Comment: Ok, well one scanf won't work because if you type anything that isn't a number scanf fails to parse it and doesn't remove it from the input.  So you need to check the return value of scanf and if it is 1 then do what you are currently doing but if it is 0 you need to do something wit hthe string that is in the input - it might be rubbish or it might be "stop".

Comment: Ok, this will work for entering multiple numbers until "stop" is entered.  It doesn't trim the input or compare case-insensitively so that could be fixed for "stop" but the rest works ok:  https://onlinegdb.com/Fsr6_bgi8   I used the prompt for the while loop - I could have used a variable holding a boolean value but we needed to change the prompt anyway...

Answer (score 1):

From reviewing the apparent functionality of this program, it is supposed to receive an integer value from the user and output the factorial of the entered value.  The fallacy in your desire to allow repeated entry of integers until the user enters the word "stop" will not work with the "scanf" function with the current formatting.  What would need to be done is to have the user enter in either the literal "stop" or an entry that looks like an integer as a character string, test for the literal "stop", exit the program if that was entered, or otherwise convert the entered character string to an integer value and then compute and print the factorial of the entered value.  With that in mind following is a refactored version of the code that would allow for repeated entry of values and a "stop" entry.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int factorial(int entry)
{
    int total = 1;

    while (entry > 1)
    {
        total *= entry;
        entry--;
    }

    return total;
}

int main()
{
    char user_entry[10];                        /* An arbitrary string size for user entry of an integer                                 */

    while (1)
    {
        printf ("Enter any integer number(positive) or \"stop\" to quit: ");
        if (scanf ("%s", user_entry) != 1)      /* The entry variable needs to be a string in order to allow entry of the literal "stop" */
            break;

        if (strcmp(user_entry, "stop") == 0)    /* This test will allow for the user to break out (exit) the "while" loop                */
            break;

        if (atoi(user_entry) == 0)              /* The atoi function converts a string into an integer - doing a validity check here     */
        {
            printf("An invalid value was entered - please retry\n");
            continue;
        }

        printf ("Total is %d\n", factorial(atoi(user_entry)));

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The key bits to note here are:

- The factorial functionality is separated and encapsulated into its own function for ease of code evaluation.
- As suspected, a "while" loop is used in the main program section to allow for repeated entry of integer values and tests within the loop for the allowance of a logical exit from the loop.
- Instead of directly receiving integer values via the "scanf" function, a character array (string) is received.
- The character array is tested to determine if the constant character value of "stop" was entered, and if so, exit out of the "while" loop and then end the program.
- If "stop" was not entered, the program continues on performing a validation that an integer value was entered, and if not, informs the user of the error, and requests a retry.
- Finally, a "printf" call is made printing out a descriptive lead along with the calculated factorial value by calling the "factorial" function, which gets the integer value via a call to the "atoi" string function.

With that, following is some test output at the terminal.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Factorial/bin/Release$ ./Factorial 
Enter any integer number(positive) or "stop" to quit: 4
Total is 24
Enter any integer number(positive) or "stop" to quit: 5
Total is 120
Enter any integer number(positive) or "stop" to quit: 6
Total is 720
Enter any integer number(positive) or "stop" to quit: quit
An invalid value was entered - please retry
Enter any integer number(positive) or "stop" to quit: stop
```

The takeaway from this code refactoring is that if various data types such as integers and strings are going to be intermixed for entries, testing and conversion of the entered data may be required.  It would be of benefit to follow up with further study from good tutorial literature, especially with the usage of strings.

Comment: `scanf ("%s", user_entry)` risks UB is input exceed 9 non-white-space characters.  Better with `fgets()` or `scanf ("%9s", user_entry)`.

Comment: `atoi(user_entry) == 0` is not a good validity check.  It behavior on error is undefined.  `strtol()` is a better approach.

Comment: The OP wants to reject negative numbers. `factorial(0)` is fully defined and returns `1` as expected.